# Enable Chrome to check English spelling

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check, english

what is the point in the latest chrome (`Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)`)?

I lost the English spelling checker, and any way to enable it, as grayed out!?!

[image]

I changed the interface to French, in order to be able to Enable the... English, restarted chrome, removed English, then restarted Chrome, added back English, but is still disabled.

I see that I am able to enable the English-US spell-checker, but not the generic English, that is not the case for the generic French and Russian, these languages can be enabled to the spell-checker...

[image]

PS. I added a new test chrome user, and open settings=> searched lang, Here I am:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the language then adding it back?  Have you tried to remove the entire user profile?  Edit your question to include this vital information.

Comment: @Ramhound, see my edit update

Comment: Should I remove my user profile? it seems like a bug in the Chrome update....

Comment: Yes;  I asked if you had tried that.  Be sure you update your question.

Comment: I didn't try it, cause it will remove all my passwords and history and navigation

Comment: So backup the profile before you delete it.

Comment: @Ramhound, what do you mean

Comment: Copy the Chrome user profile directory, to another directory, then delete the directory.  Verify the problem exists with a clean Chrome user profile.  If it does not, then we can determine, what about your profile is corrupt.

Comment: @Ramhound please see my OP update, you can reproduce it yourself, i suppose, i created a new chrome profile/user

Comment: Any news on this? I raelly ned speell chekcing!